# Unable to import keycloak even though defined in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am new to maven and keycloak.
I am trying to write a simple extension for keycloak and following the tutorial from the docs.

The problem is that even though I have defined keycloak in my dependencies in pom.xml, I am unable to import them in my code.

Here are the images of my snippet

`pom.xml`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwf2g.png)

`/src/main/java/com/example/rest/HelloResourceProviderFactory.java`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aee9s.png)

Just for testing, I tried to put spring in pom.xml, and I was able to import that.
Is there some different procedure for creating an SPI for keycloak? or is there a different way to import keycloak dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the version for your keycloak dependencies

Change `pom.xml` and add a property for your keycloak version (e.g. 6.0.1).
Use the version parameter in all your keylocak dependencies.

```
<project ...>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    ...
    <properties>
        <keycloak.version>6.0.1</keycloak.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
```